Migrate Basic Azure SQL database to vCore via Terraform
We currently have a basic database running which is setup via terraform.
module "mssql_api_db" {
  depends_on = [module.mssql_server]
  source     = "app.terraform.io/xxx/mssql_db/azurerm"
  version    = "2.0.0"

  ####################
  name             = local.api_database_name
  server_id        = module.mssql_server.mssql_server_id
  use_elastic_pool = false

  collation          = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  max_size_gb        = var.api_infra_db_size_gb
  min_capacity       = 0
  read_replica_count = 0
  read_scale         = false
  zone_redundant     = false
  sku_name           = "Basic"

We intend to switch this from the Basic sku to a vCore version as we are deploying to production soon after having finalized the family & friends test.
What is the best approach to do that? We changed the sku name to "GP_Gen5_4" but it looks like that the database is then dropped and recreated.
Is there any other way of how to migrate the database w/o loosing the already existing data.
We changed sku_name from Basic to GP_Gen5_4 and expected that the database just gets migrated but instead a new database got created and the old one dropped.

For this we can try creating before destroy operation but unfortunately Azure's SQL Database resource management in Terraform does not support the create_before_destroy lifecycle rule directly due to the nature of the underlying API operations for certain properties like sku_name. However, you can manage this migration in a way that minimizes downtime using CLI commands @kalle


Migrate Basic Azure SQL database to vCore via Terraform and CLI

In order to achieve the requirement of SQL DB of updating the Basic SKU to vCore-based SKU without losing data is not directly possible using terraform as these connections are established with API connections. Azure is provided a set of guidelines for downtime and uptime based on the resources we are using.
Because of this we cannot even use create before destroy operation. However, this to achieve we need manual intervention using CLI commands. Which in result have some significant amount of downtime while migrating happens but with this we can eliminate the destroy and recreate issue that occurs with terraform.
First, I create the SQL DB with Basic SKU and in order to update the sku type.

Take the backup manually and update the SKU using the CLI command below
az sql db update --resource-group vinay-resources --server vinay-sqlserver --name vinay-api-db --service-objective GP_Gen5_4

This will take some downtime however it won't destroy and recreate.
Now rewrite the terraform scirpt which matches with sku mentioned.
Terraform configuration:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "vinay-resources"
  location = "East US"
}


resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "vinay-sqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "sqladmin"
  administrator_login_password = "H@Sh1CoR3!"
}


resource "azurerm_mssql_database" "example" {
  name           = local.api_database_name
  server_id      = azurerm_mssql_server.example.id
  collation      = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
  license_type   = "LicenseIncluded"
  max_size_gb    = var.api_infra_db_size_gb
  sku_name       = "GP_Gen5_4"
  zone_redundant = false
  enclave_type   = "VBS"
  min_capacity   = 0
  read_scale = true

}


variable "api_infra_db_size_gb" {
  type    = number
  default = 10
}


locals {
  api_database_name = "vinay-api-db"
}

Deployment succeeded:

Here the only change is takes place with size which changes with the respective SKU

reference:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_database#sku_name
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/sql/db?view=azure-cli-latest#az-sql-db-update

@Kalle Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

Thanks a lot @Vinay - this helped us a lot :)
